# Cannot setValue in MutableLiveData using object retrieved using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-livedata

I am trying to follow Android architecture guidelines to make this app. I have a MovieRepository which is responsible for fetching JSON (data layer), and I have a ViewModel that supplies data to the UI in my MainActivity. I am using retrofit 2 for my networking task.

MovieRespository code:

```
public class MovieRepository {

    private static final String TAG = MovieRepository.class.getSimpleName();

    public LiveData<ReturnMovie> search(String term) {
        final MutableLiveData<ReturnMovie> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

        MovieService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(MovieService.class);
        Call<ReturnMovie> call = service.requestMovie(term, MovieAPIUtils.KEY);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ReturnMovie>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ReturnMovie> call, Response<ReturnMovie> response) {
                ReturnMovie movie = response.body();
                data.setValue(movie);
                Log.d(TAG, data.getValue().getPage().toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ReturnMovie> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
        return data;
    }
}
```

MovieService:

```
public interface MovieService {

    @GET(MovieAPIUtils.Path.MOVIE_PATH + "/{param}")
    Call<ReturnMovie> requestMovie (@Path("param") String endpoints,
                                    @Query(MovieAPIUtils.Query.API_QUERY) String key);

}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainActivityMovieViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivityMovieViewModel.class.getSimpleName();

    private LiveData<ReturnMovie> movie;
    private MovieRepository repo = new MovieRepository();

    public LiveData<ReturnMovie> getMovie(String searchTerm) {

        if (movie == null) {
            movie = repo.search(searchTerm);
        }

        return movie;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MovieAdapter.MovieOnClickListener {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MovieAdapter mMovieAdapter;
    private MainActivityMovieViewModel viewModel;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityMovieViewModel.class);
        initRecyclerViewWithMovies();

        ReturnMovie movie = viewModel.getMovie(MovieAPIUtils.Endpoints.POPULAR_ENDPOINT).getValue();

// other code....

    }
```

In the `onResponse(new Callback<ReturnMovie>)` I was able to retrieve the movie object and I proved it by logging one of its property values, so there IS a valid ReturnMovie object. However, in my `MainActivity`, the method `ReturnMovie movie = viewModel.getMovie(MovieAPIUtils.Endpoints.POPULAR_ENDPOINT).getValue();` gives me a null. I checked everywhere is just cannot see where the problem is.

The rest of the code is on my Github:
https://github.com/brendoncheung/PopularMovie/tree/mvvm_approach

Answer (score 1):

You use android architecture components, which uses observable pattern in live data. If you are just getting the current value of livedata, you are not sure it has been processed yet. 
Instead of 
`ReturnMovie movie = viewModel.getMovie(MovieAPIUtils.Endpoints.POPULAR_ENDPOINT).getValue();` i think you should use

```
viewModel.getMovie(MovieAPIUtils.Endpoints.POPULAR_ENDPOINT).observe(this, new Observer<ReturnMovie>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable ReturnMovie movie) {
          //do stuff with the movie
          doSomething(movie);
        }
    });
```

You don't have to manage unsubscription since architecture component manages unsubscription for activities itself

Take a look on : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata